# What causes a process to restart every time I force quit it?

Tags: macos, boot, process, pid

So I think I've removed hamachi from startup. Done. Dusted. When after a restart a load up a server for a friend to connect. Then noticed he could connect without starting up hamachi. Hmm. Curious.

I restart my computer and look in the activity monitor.

[image: Activity monitor screenshot]

Upon force quitting the process, it just restarts itself.
I've noticed it's started rather early on. Here are it's parent processes if this helps. I have no clue. Not very good with this sorta stuff.

[image]

How does one simply stop the process on startup and it restarting whenever quit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upon login, many applications startup. These are shown as the login items in the System Preferences --> Users & Groups --> Login items.

These are easily visible however there are other processes that aren't applications that start up behind the scenes.

> OS X 10.4 Tiger, Apple has given developers another mechanism for launching items automatically: launch daemons and agents, controlled by the launchd process. This approach provides more flexibility than either login items or startup items, but it is less transparent to users.

This means there are other mechanisms for launching processes.

> The .plist files that launchd uses can occupy any of five folders, and their location determines when the items load and with what privileges:
>
> Items in /Library/LaunchDaemons and /System/Library/LaunchDaemons load when your Mac starts up, and run as the root user.
>
> Items in /Library/LaunchAgents and /System/Library/LaunchAgents load when any user logs in, and run as that user.
>
> Items in /Users/your-username/Library/LaunchAgents load only when that particular user logs in, and run as that user.

After venturing to these folders you will find files named:

com.logmein.hamachimb.plist in /Library/LaunchAgents
and
com.logmein.hamachi.plist in /Library/LaunchDaemons

There are no hamachi files in the /System/...
files It warns not to venture into these files as you may end up breaking something.

> Keep your hands off of some: Of those five folders, the two located in the /System folder (/System/Library/LaunchDaemons and /System/Library/LaunchAgents) are for components included as part of OS X, and you should resist the temptation to remove or alter them—they’re essential to keep your Mac running correctly.
>
> Modify others as you like: As for the items in the other folders, feel free to browse through them and see what’s there. You can modify them—for instance, to disable them or to change how often they run—but before you do, you should understand a few things about how they work.

As for items in the folders it says you can modify, I'd reccomend just taking a backup in a folder named the file path and then deleting the ones in the 'LaunchAgents' and 'LaunchDaemons' folders.

After this, when opening activity monitor, no processes related to Hamachi are running. Voilà!

Source (With thanks to 'TG2'): http://www.macworld.com/article/2047747/take-control-of-startup-and-login-items.html

Answer (score 1):

Try here ... detailed with screen shots and directories of the most common locations.  Word of warning, if they say look but don't touch .. trust them.

http://www.macworld.com/article/2047747/take-control-of-startup-and-login-items.html